# How do I cancel my UKVI application when I have sent biometrics

Tags: visas, uk

I am struggling to find the option to cancel my UKVI application. I am from South Africa and used the TLS system to book an appointment, but the station I chose is currently closed. I now have to cancel my entire application in order to change this location, but cannot find the direct link on the UKVI platform.

Comment: Have you tried via https://pos.tlscontact.com/cpt_en/contact?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Finally got a resolution. If you haven't booked an appointment, just submit another application.

(BTW I tried contacting TLS through their contact sheet with no response)

Comment: How were you advised (or how did you learn) the prior application was cancelled?